# Properties in the are model null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, typescript

When data comes to the `WebApi controller`, the model comes, but it has all `null` properties.

I tried to see if the data is in `var data = new StreamReader (HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream). ReadToEnd ();` And it turned out that they are.

```
// POST: api/Events
public void PostSome(NewEventVm eventVm)
{
    var data = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
}
```

**Typescript**

```
submitEventForm(): void {
debugger;
this.event.Image = this.image;
let postData = { eventVm: this.event };
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
let body = JSON.stringify(postData);
var a = this.http.post("/EventsModuleApi/Events/PostSome", body, options).toPromise(this.result);};
```

[image]

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: If this is dot net core then you need the [FromBody] attribute on the `NewEventVm` parameter.

Comment: Along with @Silvermind comment above, ensure to tag your `PostSome` method with the relevant [`[HttpPost]`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) tag.

Comment: @Silvermind Not correct, if the JSON is part of the HTTP body (which it should be) then ASP.NET will automatically use that without FromBody.

Comment: @Sandman, Method with `HttpPost` tag

Comment: @Lightness, it works? Or you need clarification?

Comment: @Sandman, It doesnt work

Comment: @user9993 Don't be so hasty with your comment and read mine carefully first. If it is asp .net core then you are obligated to add it, but in .net framework you don't have to supply it. That's why I mentioned .net core to clarify it with the op. See also https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json doesn't match your model.

This line:

```
let postData = { eventVm: this.event };
```

will post an object containing another object, which is your model. Change it to:

```
let postData = this.event;
```

Assuming `this.event` contains the same properties as your `NewEventVm` class, Web API will deserialize it correctly into your parameter.